# cosine similarity between all documents in a list python

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

I have two types of documents and I want to know on an average how similar they are.

doc1list=[" I like apples", "apples are healthy", " health is wealth"]

doc2list=["i am about fruits" , "vegetables are good","eating out is bad"]

I want to calculate average cosine similarity for each of these 2 lists of documents and compare the two lists.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from scipy import linalg, mat, dot

count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
matrix=count_vectorizer.fit_transform(doc1list) 
c = dot(matrix,matrix.T)/linalg.norm(matrix)/linalg.norm(matrix)
print(c)
```

but this gives an error
raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
ValueError: dimension mismatch

Comment: what are the dimensions of `matrix`?

Comment: I got it, it produces a sparse representation and hence this error. I'd have to see how to change it to non-sparse representation